# Searchbox of a searchable column in jqgrid should be disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I know that jqGrid can make a programmer's life easy by taking care of small things by itself. But I just want it not to do some things for me and I don't know where and how I should tell the jqGrid so. When a searchable column in the grid is searched for a certain search string, and when the grid loads, I want all the search boxes disabled. I have found the dynamic IDs of the td tags that are generated when its rendered.

I just want to know if there is a way I can handle such events in jqGrid manually and if I can, where should I do so?

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config

Comment: @epascarello that link is not going to help him...

Comment: I stumbled upon that link long back. I didn't know whether or not it will help me. I didn't even understand what they were trying to say in there. It's just a catalog for jqGrid, which unfortunately a beginner like me can't comprehend.